# C2039 'XamlTypeInfo': is not a member of 'winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml' in XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp

Tags: c++, uwp, windows-10-universal, c++-winrt

I add [Microsoft::UI::Xaml](https://github.com/microsoft/microsoft-ui-xaml) NuGet package to my C++/WinRT Blank App project will raised error.

Output message:

> 1>------ Rebuild All started: Project: TxtRecordGenerator,
>   Configuration: Debug x64 ------ 1>64 bit MIDLRT Processing
>   C:\Users\a124p\Documents\GitHub\VisualizationRecorder\TxtRecordGenerator\App.idl
>   1>App.idl 1>64 bit MIDLRT Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\winrt\winrtbase.idl 1>winrtbase.idl 1>64
>   bit MIDLRT Processing C:\Program Files (x86)\Windows
>   Kits\10\Include\10.0.18362.0\winrt\midlbase.idl 1>midlbase.idl
>   1>Processing WinMD
>   1>Processing input metadata file x64\Debug\Unmerged\App.winmd.
>   1>Processing input metadata file x64\Debug\Unmerged\MainPage.winmd.
>   1>Processing input metadata file
>   x64\Debug\Unmerged\XamlMetaDataProvider.winmd. 1>Saved output metadata
>   file TxtRecordGenerator.winmd. 1>Validating metadata file
>   x64\Debug\Merged\TxtRecordGenerator.winmd. 1>pch.cpp 1>App.cpp
>   1>MainPage.cpp 1>module.g.cpp 1>XamlTypeInfo.Impl.g.cpp
>   1>XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp
>   1>C:\Users\a124p\Documents\GitHub\VisualizationRecorder\TxtRecordGenerator\Generated
>   Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(919,77): error C2039: 'XamlTypeInfo': is not
>   a member of 'winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml'
>   1>C:\Users\a124p\Documents\GitHub\VisualizationRecorder\TxtRecordGenerator\Generated
>   Files\winrt\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.h(16562): message : see
>   declaration of 'winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml'
>   1>C:\Users\a124p\Documents\GitHub\VisualizationRecorder\TxtRecordGenerator\Generated
>   Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(919,65): error C3083: 'XamlTypeInfo': the
>   symbol to the left of a '::' must be a type
>   1>C:\Users\a124p\Documents\GitHub\VisualizationRecorder\TxtRecordGenerator\Generated
>   Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(919,79): error C2039:
>   'XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider': is not a member of
>   'winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml'
>   1>C:\Users\a124p\Documents\GitHub\VisualizationRecorder\TxtRecordGenerator\Generated
>   Files\winrt\Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.h(16562): message : see
>   declaration of 'winrt::Microsoft::UI::Xaml'
>   1>C:\Users\a124p\Documents\GitHub\VisualizationRecorder\TxtRecordGenerator\Generated
>   Files\XamlTypeInfo.g.cpp(919,111): error C3861:
>   'XamlControlsXamlMetaDataProvider': identifier not found 1>Done
>   building project "TxtRecordGenerator.vcxproj" -- FAILED.
>   ========== Rebuild All: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

This seems to be the error WinRT C++ code generator caused.

The C++/WinRT project code file as follows:

pch.h code:

```
#pragma once
#include <windows.h>
#include <unknwn.h>
#include <restrictederrorinfo.h>
#include <hstring.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.ApplicationModel.Activation.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Primitives.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Data.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Interop.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.h>
#include <winrt/Windows.UI.Xaml.Navigation.h>
#include <winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls.h>
```

MainPage.idl:

```
namespace TxtRecordGenerator
{
    [default_interface]
    runtimeclass MainPage : Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page
    {
        MainPage();
    }
}
```

MainPage.h:

```
#pragma once

#include "MainPage.g.h"

namespace winrt::TxtRecordGenerator::implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage>
    {
        MainPage();
    };
}

namespace winrt::TxtRecordGenerator::factory_implementation
{
    struct MainPage : MainPageT<MainPage, implementation::MainPage>
    {
    };
}
```

MainPage.cpp:

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "MainPage.h"
#include "MainPage.g.cpp"

using namespace winrt;
using namespace Windows::UI::Xaml;

namespace winrt::TxtRecordGenerator::implementation
{
    MainPage::MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

MainPage.xaml:

```
<Page
    x:Class="TxtRecordGenerator.MainPage"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:TxtRecordGenerator"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls"
    mc:Ignorable="d">

    <Grid>
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition/>
            <RowDefinition/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
            <ColumnDefinition/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="BeginDatePicker" 
                            PlaceholderText="Pick a date" 
                            Header="Begin Date" 
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorLight1}" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.Column="0" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <CalendarDatePicker x:Name="EndDatePicker" 
                            PlaceholderText="Pick a date" 
                            Header="End Date" 
                            Foreground="{ThemeResource SystemAccentColorLight1}" 
                            Grid.Row="0" 
                            Grid.Column="1" 
                            HorizontalAlignment="Center" 
                            VerticalAlignment="Center" />
        <controls:NumberBox x:Name="BeginNumberBox"
                   Header="Enter an integer:" 
                   Value="1" 
                   SpinButtonPlacementMode="Compact" 
                   SmallChange="10"
                   LargeChange="100"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="0"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
        <controls:NumberBox x:Name="EndNumberBox"
                   Header="Enter an integer:" 
                   Value="1" 
                   SpinButtonPlacementMode="Compact" 
                   SmallChange="10"
                   LargeChange="100"
                   Grid.Row="1"
                   Grid.Column="1"
                   HorizontalAlignment="Center"
                   VerticalAlignment="Center"/>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Development Environment:

- IDE: Visual Studio 2019

  UWP project target version: Windows 10, version 1903(10.0; Build
  18362)

  UWP project min version: Windows 10, version 1903(10.0; Build 18362)

This question confuses me. Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you need to declare WinUI application resources in App.xaml:

```
<Application ......>
    <Application.Resources>
        <XamlControlsResources xmlns="using:Microsoft.UI.Xaml.Controls" />
    </Application.Resources>
</Application>
```

Then also add the following header file.

```
#include "winrt/Microsoft.UI.Xaml.XamlTypeInfo.h"
```

About more details, you can refer to this document: [A simple C++/WinRT Windows UI Library example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/cpp-and-winrt-apis/simple-winui-example).